# Handler.ashx C# to Java, ExtJs based File and Image Manager plugin for TinyMCE

Tags: c#, spring, extjs, tinymce

I am using ExtJsFileManager developed by Rahul Singla
http://www.rahulsingla.com/blog/2011/05/extjsfilemanager-extjs-based-file-and-image-manager-plugin-for-tinymce

here are Php and C# examples, and there are filehandlers for it. I am using Java SpringSource in my project and I am new to these technologies. I have tried to convert C# to Java but I dont understand exactly what C# returns to the client.

here is workind C# codes

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="BrowserHandler" %>

using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security;
using MyCompany;

public class BrowserHandler : IHttpHandler
{

#region Private Members
private HttpContext context;
#endregion

#region IHttpHandler Methods
public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context)
{
    this.context = context;
    string op=context.Request["op"];
    string path=this.context.Request["path"];
    context.Response.ContentType = "text/javascript";

    //These are extra parameters you can pass to the server in each request by specifying extjsfilemanager_extraparams option in init.
    string param1=context.Request["param1"];
    string param2=context.Request["param2"];

    switch (op)
    {
        case "getFolders":
            this.getFolders(path);
            break;

        case "getFiles":
            this.getFiles(path);
            break;

        case "createFolder":
            this.createFolder(path);
            break;

        case "uploadFiles":
            this.uploadFiles(path);
            break;
    }
}

public bool IsReusable
{
    get
    {
        return false;
    }
}
#endregion

#region Private Methods
private void getFolders (string path)
{
    path = this.validatePath(path);

    List<object> l=new List<object>();
    foreach (string dir in Directory.GetDirectories(path))
    {
        l.Add(new
        {
            text = Path.GetFileName(dir),
            path = dir,
            leaf = false,
            singleClickExpand = true
        });
    }

    this.context.Response.Write(Globals.serializer.Serialize(l));
}

private void getFiles (string path)
{
    path = this.validatePath(path);

    List<object> l=new List<object>();
    foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(path))
    {
        l.Add(new
        {
            text = Path.GetFileName(file),
            virtualPath = Globals.resolveUrl(Globals.resolveVirtual(file))
        });
    }

    this.context.Response.Write(Globals.serializer.Serialize(l));
}

private void createFolder (string path)
{
    path = this.validatePath(path);

    string name=this.context.Request["name"];
    Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(path, name));

    this.context.Response.Write(Globals.serializer.Serialize(new object()));
}

private void uploadFiles (string path)
{
    context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";
    path = this.validatePath(path);

    string successFiles="";
    string errorFiles="";

    for (int i=0; i < this.context.Request.Files.Count; i++)
    {
        HttpPostedFile file=this.context.Request.Files[i];

        if (file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            string fileName=file.FileName;
            string extension=Path.GetExtension(fileName);
            //Remove .
            if (extension.Length > 0) extension = extension.Substring(1);

            if (Config.allowedUploadExtensions.Contains(extension, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                file.SaveAs(Path.Combine(path, fileName));
            }
            else
            {
                errorFiles += string.Format("Extension for {0} is not allowed.<br />", fileName);
            }
        }
    }

    string s=Globals.serializer.Serialize(new
    {
        success = true,
        successFiles,
        errorFiles
    });
    byte[] b=this.context.Response.ContentEncoding.GetBytes(s);
    this.context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", b.Length.ToString());

    this.context.Response.BinaryWrite(b);

    try
    {
        this.context.Response.Flush();
        this.context.Response.End();
        this.context.Response.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception) { }
}

private string validatePath (string path)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
    {
        path = Config.baseUploadDirPhysical;
    }

    if (!path.StartsWith(Config.baseUploadDirPhysical, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) || (path.IndexOf("..") != -1))
    {
        throw new SecurityException("Invalid path.");
    }

    return (path);
}
#endregion}
```

and here is my codes

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/filehandler", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody byte[] filehandler(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    String op = request.getParameter("op");
    String path = uploadDataFolder; // || request.getParameter("path");
    String jsondata = "{root:";
    String datastr = "";

    File folder = new File(path);

    if (op.equals( "getFolders")){
        // FOLDERS
        for (File fileEntry : folder.listFiles() ) {
            //File fileEntry;
            if (fileEntry.isDirectory()) {
                datastr += "{\"text\":\"" + fileEntry.getName() +
                            "\",\"path\":\"" + fileEntry.getPath() +
                            "\",\"leaf\":\"false\"" +
                            ",\"singleClickExpand\":\"true\"}";
            }
        }
    }
    else if (op == "getFiles"){
        // FILES
        for (File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
            //File fileEntry;
            if (fileEntry.isFile()) {
                datastr += "{\"text\":\"" + fileEntry.getName() +
                            "\",\"virtualPath\":\"" + fileEntry.getPath() + "\"";
            } else {
                System.out.println(fileEntry.getName());
            }
        }
    }
    else if (op == "createFolder"){
        // create folder function is not supported in our project

    }
    else if (op == "uploadFiles"){
        // upload images
        request.getAttribute("Files");
    }
    datastr = datastr.equals("") ? "null" :  "[" + datastr + "]";
    jsondata += datastr + "}";

    return getBytes(jsondata);
}
```

For getFolders operation, it returns JSON data such that

```
{root:[{"text":"blog","path":"C:\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\NetaCommerceFrameworkAdmin\META-INF\static\images\blog","leaf":"false","singleClickExpand":"true"}{"text":"photos","path":"C:\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\NetaCommerceFrameworkAdmin\META-INF\static\images\photos","leaf":"false","singleClickExpand":"true"}]}
```

I cant figure out what C# codes returns, so I cannot write it in Java. it does not allow my JSON returned by operation "getFolders".

Comment: The most important part missing is class `Globals.serializer` and it's method `Serialize`. Does your C# project compile? It seems it produces JSON from C# objects.

Answer (score 2):

A C# 'HTTPHandler' can return what it wants, in that it may for example return an image (a common use) or it could return binary file data which gives the client to download a file.

They are flexible and can be configured to 'return' anything as often they write directly to the HTTPResponse object.

In order to work out what your handler is returning you want to be looking for anything which touches the HTTPResponse.

e.g. `context.Response.ContentType = "text/javascript";`

This is setting the content type headers on the Http response.

A couple of the private methods in there seem to generate lists, and returned those serialised to the client which looks like just JSON data.

The exception here is the `uploadFiles()` method which appears to take a post request (you can tell as it's trying to access the request object to retrieve an uploaded file here:

```
HttpPostedFile file=this.context.Request.Files[i];
```

Which appears to save the file to the server after some checks.

If I were you, I'd look in the Java API's for their own serialiser options and see if you can hook into that, rather than writing your own method to stick strings together.

Comment: actually, I have coded file upload for java before, and it works. it doesnt matter. here, I dont know what client code expect as json data. but, I tried many versions and now I catch it: `[{-file1datas-}, {-file2datas-}]`
but now I have another problem, \'s in file path is removed when converting Json data. As you say, to use java json serializer is the best.. thank you